# Number of truths in a propositional statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose I have a statement made of many propositions.

$\left(a \rightarrow b\right) \wedge \left(c \oplus d\right) \vee \left(e\wedge f\right) \dots$

composed of the standard 16 binary operators. Is there a way to know how many truths there will be in the truth table? That doesn't involve putting all combinations of 1 and 0 in to evaluate them?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-SAT) is intractable and [#P-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-complete).

Comment: What do you mean by intractable?

I have created a method that solves this problem. I'm not sure if it has been done before though?

Comment: and if I just read that #P-complete article correctly. Then if I have done what I claim to have done, then somehow it relates to P=NP?

Comment: @BenCrossley "Intractable" means that any algorithm that attempts to solve the problem will take "more than polynomially longer as a function of problem size" in finding the solution. Generally, exponentially longer. Here, the problem size is given by the number of variables. Your method may work for 20 variables, but once it's 200 variables, you will wait forevermore for the algorithm to finish. More specifically, going through 2^20 possibilites vs going through 2^200 possibilities. This is somewhat weakly related to "P=NP" (of course NP will never be P, that would be sheer magic)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Just to make sure I understand. The problem is whether or not the time it takes to solve for each additional variable grows exponentially?

Comment: @BenCrossley Well, yes. There is no better way (in general) to find "the number of times a given proposition resolves to true" than to use the brute-force method of going through all possible inputs and evaluating. So, for an expression in x,y,z you have to check 000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111 ... 2^3 evaluations. For an expression with hundreds (or millions, not unheard of) variables you have 2^100 tests to make, you will not be able to count the number of solutions. The universe won't last long enough to go through the table.

Comment: @BenCrossley On the other hand, for some *specific* formulas, you may be able to throw away large areas of the table to search immediately by a little forethought, for example if your formula is "x & some-expression-in-x,y,z", you immediately know that x must be 1.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer I have stumbled across a binary operation that allows me to go directly from a modified "boolean algebra" statement to the number of truth values.

I say "boolean algebra" because I'm not 100% sure what that term means to other people. To me, it means NOT $a \equiv 1-a$ and $a$ AND $b \equib ab$(using standard algebraic operations.

Comment: @BenCrossley Why not post a gist at github?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer The calculations are all pen and paper. I’ve just started teaching myself python so that I may be able to code it up. Defining the new binary operation may be fun.

Comment: @BenCrossley Uh-hu. Don't get your hopes up on having cracked a known hard problem though. They are known hard for a good reason. Check out [SAT solving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) for related fun.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer yeah. That is what I have a solution to. I am trying very hard to stay rational. I expect there will be some technical reason why my solution isn’t valid. But atm it has worked on everything thrown at it with 100% accuracy.

Comment: @DavidTohner having read the SAT article again I’ve realised that my method is overkill. It doesn’t just answer whether or not a truth exists, it provides the number of solutions. Presumably there will be a way to sacrifice some power for speed. I’ll get working on that.